# display array elements modulo 5?

Tags: php

I have an array which is converted to string and it looks like this: `00:00,05:00,10:00,15:00,20:00` it shows hours range every 5 hours,
I want to display my string like this `, , , ,5:00, , , , ,10:00, , , , ,15:00, , , , ,20:00, , , ,`
so display it every 5 hours but hours that are not needed i want to set empty,

code:

```
    $date = new \DateTime("12:00am");
    $dv = new \DateInterval('PT5H');
    $totalInterval = 4 ; 
    $dr = array();
    $date->format('H:i');
    for($i = 0; $i < $totalInterval; $i++)
    {

        $dr[] = $date->format('H:i');
        $date->add($dv);

    }
    $dr[] = $date->format('H:i');   
    $dr = implode (',', $dr);
```

How would I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dr = ' , , , ,' . implode (', , , , ,', $dr) . ', , , , ';
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `$dr[] = $date->format('H:i');` to:

```
array_push($dr, '', '', '', '', $date->format('H:i'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the necessary empty entries:

```
$hours = 5;
$dv = new \DateInterval('PT'.$hours.'H');
...
for( $i=0; $i<$totalInterval; $i++) {
    for( $off=0; $off<$hours-1; $off++) $dr[] = " ";
    $dr[] = $date->format('H:i');
    ...
}
...
echo implode(',',$dr);
```